# Xubuntu 18.04 freezes after upgrade from 16.04

Tags: xubuntu, freeze, amd-graphics, amdgpu, amd-ryzen

I recently updated from 16.04 to 18.04. Almost immediately afterward, I've noticed an issue where the computer would almost completely freeze. I can still move the mouse around, but can't click on anything (or rather, when I click nothing happens). The keyboard is similarly unresponsive. Not even <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>Backspace</kbd> to restart X or the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>F*</kbd> combo to get a text terminal seems to do anything. What does seem to work is the <kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>sysRq</kbd>-<kbd>REISUB</kbd> combo to reboot.

I'm not doing anything particularly out of the ordinary when it happens. I have observed it when I've done practically nothing since I restarted than log in and browse the web with Firefox.

Consulting gnome-system-log, it seems like right before the hang I get a bunch of messages in the syslog section like:

```
kernel: [ 5818.723368] gmc_v9_0_process_interrupt: 19 callbacks suppressed
kernel: [ 5818.723372] amdgpu 0000:08:00.0: [gfxhub] VMC page fault (src_id:0 ring:24 vm_id:1 pas_id:0)
kernel: [ 5818.723376] amdgpu 0000:08:00.0:   at page 0x0000000105405000 from 27
...
```

I am using an AMD Ryzen 3 2200G CPU with integrated Radeon Vega 8 Graphics (desktop system).

Given that this happens with some regularity (and wasn't happening before I updated to 18.04), I'd like to figure out what's causing it and fix it. Is there anything I should try, or other diagnostics I should run?

---

*Mandatory "things I've tried from other answers which don't work" section:*

- I've checked and I should be up-to-date with all the packages which are installed. (Reasonably, since I just updated to 18.04 a few days ago.)
- I've looked into upgrading my graphics drivers, and to my knowledge they should be up-to-date.
- There's various mentions of disabling "cool and quiet" and the C6 state using a "ZenStates" script. I've tried both, and still am having issues.
- GSmartControl gives a clean bill of health to my sda drive, even when the short self test is run.